# Undefined Laplace Transform

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform

I'm in calculus II and our teacher gave us a problem as follows:  Let f(t) be a function defined for all positive values of t.  The Laplace Transform of f(t) is defined by: $$F(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt$$
Find the Laplace Transform of the function: $$f(t) = t^2$$

We haven't learned about Laplace Transforms, but I did some Google searching about it to figure out what to do.  We're covering improper integrals right now.  When I calculated this I got that the result is undefined for all values of s.  The following is all of my steps, but I'm not sure if I made a mistake somewhere because in all of the examples I've seen , Laplace Transforms usually go to 0 depending on the sign of the constant s.  Can anyone verify if I did this correctly?

I first put the integral into limit form.

$$=\lim_{b\to\infty}\int_0^b{e^{-st}t^2dt}$$

Then compute the integral using integration by parts:

$$=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[-\dfrac{t^2e^{-st}}{s}\Bigg|_0^b + \dfrac{2}{s}\int_0^\infty te^{-st}dt\right]$$
Then using integration by parts again:

$$=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[-\dfrac{t^2e^{-st}}{s}\Bigg|_0^b + \dfrac{2}{s}\left[ \dfrac{-te^{-st}}{s}\Bigg|_0^b + \dfrac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty e^{-st}dt\right]\space\right]$$

Then take the last integral:

$$=\lim_{b\to\infty}\left[-\dfrac{t^2e^{-st}}{s}\Bigg|_0^b + \dfrac{2}{s}\left[ \dfrac{-te^{-st}}{s}\Bigg|_0^b + \dfrac{1}{s}\times\left(\dfrac{-e^{-st}}{s}\right)\right]\space\right]$$

Simplifying that I got:

$$=\lim_{b\to\infty}-\dfrac{t^2e^{-st}}{s}\Bigg|_0^b+\dfrac{2te^{-st}}{s^2}\Bigg|_0^b - \dfrac{2e^{-st}}{s^3}\Bigg|_0^b$$

Then when you take the limit plug in infinity for b, I got:
$$-\dfrac{\infty e^{-s\infty}}{s} - \dfrac{2\infty e^{-s\infty}}{s^2} - \dfrac {2e^{-s\infty}}{s^3}$$

So I said the transform was undefined for all values of s because if s is negative, you get infinity minus infinity and if it's positive, you get infinities divided infinities, both of which are undefined.  Is that correct?

Comment: How could I get to that answer without using a table?  In other words, was the method I used above completely wrong?  Since we  haven't learned about this yet, I just got there by following some examples I read.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think to pull the third part out in front of the limit.  That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all by definition of Laplace transformation s is greater than 0. and (s does not have to be complex unless it specified to be  complex). and since you did not plug zero at the final term -2/(s^3)(e^st) you miss the term 2/s^3. and as to calculating limit when b goes to infinity s>0 by definition of Laplace then realize  that b/e^(bs) goes to zero since denominator grow faster than numerator.or you can get infinity over infinity and by L hopital again you get that all the terms go to zero except for 2/s^3.
(b

Comment: Thank you, yeah I realized the main mistake I made was not bringing the constants out in front of the limits and as you said, not plugging in 0.  Thanks for the clarification.  I was also wondering about what @stefano said about s being a complex number, so I'm glad to know it doesn't HAVE to be complex...that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First recall that $s$ is a complex number. The region of convergence is $Re(s)>0$. In this way, when you take the limit, the last expression you wrote goes to zero. Then remember also to plug in $t=0$ to get the correct answer $\frac{2}{s^3}$ (you can check it in the table provided my @Amzoti).

Comment: When I originally calculated this, I did note that the third expression would go to zero with a positive s value, but here's what confuses me.  The first two expresses are undefined, correct?  If so, how can you isolate just the third expression?  I thought any expression with an undefined part is just undefined?

Comment: The limit of the first two expressions goes to zero: for $s>0$
$lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{t^2}{e^{st}} = 0$, and similarly the second one.